# Some objects vanish when window is minimized in my XNA game

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, 2d, minimize

I'm building a game in XNA 4.0 and C# and am running into an issue when I try to make the game run fullscreen or when I minimize the window and bring it back. Basically, one of the objects in my game (the doors), always vanish and do not come back.

Does anyone know what exactly happens when the window is minimized and why the door may be behaving differently than other elements in the game?

Comment: Sounds like something isn't being repainted properly.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but if I recall from my XNA-tinkering days, you have to explicitly reallocate certain resources like textures, etc, in these cases - possibly you're losing a texture?

Answer (score 1):

Check the update and draw loops and make sure your doors are being both updated and redrawn.

When you change the size of the window and objects disappear, there is usually an error somewhere with the redrawing of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and it was very tricky. What happened had to do with window resizing, as I was using 1366 x 768 when my computer's monitor is only 1280 x 800. Naturally, some of the game is always clipped, but on minimizing, the clipping changed very subtley.

The best fix was to just start putting elements within my own screen resolution. I'm now coding assuming a resolution of 1280 x 768.